# angular 6 with jsonplaceholder , opening posts/${id} after clicking button

Tags: json, angular

I am working on a dummy app with jsonplaceholder, I am getting all posts but i am unable to get post with dynamic id like posts/${id}. How can i achieve this. kindly help.
I am having basic generate angular app.

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<!--  -->
<main *ngIf="!some; else elseBlock">
    <section *ngFor="let dt of data">
        <aside>ID:  <span id="id">{{dt.id}}</span></aside>
        <aside>Title:  {{dt.title}}</aside>
        <button (click)="linkto()">click to view</button>
        <br>
        <hr>
    </section>
</main>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
    <section>
        <aside>ID:  {{data2.id}}</aside>
        <aside>Title:  {{data2.title}}</aside>
        <aside>Body:  {{data2.body}}</aside>
        <button (click)="linkto()">back</button>
        <br>
        <hr>
    </section>
</ng-template>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  constructor(private http : HttpClient){
    this.showPost();
  }
  data :any = [];
  id: any;
  data2 :any = {};
  some: boolean;
  showPost() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    // clone the data object, using its known Config shape
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log('**************',data);
      this.data = data
    });
  }
  linkto(){
    this.showPost2();
    this.some = !this.some;
  }
  showPost2() {
    this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
    .subscribe(data2 => {
      this.data2 = data2;
    });
  }

}
```

i am also interested if is there any shorter way to do this?
like simple on one page . i am making get requests but after this i will be making post, put , patch and delete too. on app.component.html page itself.

Comment: what is that `id`? you didn't have `id` in the parameter

Comment: yes , i know . i want to go to " https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 " if i click my button on first post and similar for second post i need to go " https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2 ". how to achieve this. i just place id randomly . you may do as necessarily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send `id` from `html` to `component` using `linkto(dt.id)`

Then you can use that `id` as a `parameter` in your `component` methods.

**HTML:**

```
<main *ngIf="!some; else elseBlock">
    <section *ngFor="let dt of data">
        <aside>ID:  <span id="id">{{dt.id}}</span></aside>
        <aside>Title:  {{dt.title}}</aside>
        <button (click)="linkto(dt.id)">click to view</button>
        <br>
        <hr>
    </section>
</main>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
    <section>
        <aside>ID:  {{data2.id}}</aside>
        <aside>Title:  {{data2.title}}</aside>
        <aside>Body:  {{data2.body}}</aside>
        <button (click)="linkto(dt.id)">back</button>
        <br>
        <hr>
    </section>
</ng-template>
```

**Component:**

```
 linkto(id){
    this.showPost2(id);
    this.some = !this.some;
  }
  showPost2(id) {
    this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
    .subscribe(data2 => {
      this.data2 = data2;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much , I dint need dt.id argument in linkto() inside #elseBlock , again Thanks now . its working fine!

Comment: @ManishVashisth, glad to help you. You can vote and accept my answer, if you find it useful

Comment: updated : I do need data2.id instead dt.id in #elseBlock, Otherwise i was getting errors in console.
Athough Its working fine now.
Thanks again.

Comment: @ManishVashisth, got your requirement?

Comment: @QusaySaad, yes please